# How to change a histogram to a line-chart in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I was wondering how I could change the histogram (see `h = hist()` below) to a line-chart as shown in the picture below?

**Here is what I tried (with no success):**

```
set.seed(0)
hyp = rhyper(1e3, 12, 5, 7)
h = hist(hyp, plot = FALSE)
plot(hyp, xlim = range(hyp), ylim = range(h$counts), type = "h", lwd = 2)
```

### To be clear, I am trying to plot:

`table(hyp)`

```
# > hyp
# >  2   3   4   5   6   7  # X-axis
# >  2  66 253 404 240  35  # Y-axis
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the `table` and then plot

```
with(data.frame(table(hyp)), plot(x = as.numeric(as.character(hyp)), y = Freq, type = "h"))
```

OR following seems to work too

```
plot(table(hyp))
```